# How to make ConsumerIrManager transmit quicker?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating Android app, which need to send a lot of IR signals per second. Unfortunately, `ConsumerIrManager.transmit` blocks process, and I'm unable to send more than 5-6 requests/second.

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                irManager.transmit(frequency, volup);
                Log.v("LEFT", "UP");
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                irManager.transmit(frequency, voldown);
                Log.v("LEFT", "DOWN");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well without code we can't do anything to help you. However, IR is not a high bandwidth channel, so it may not be possible to increase your throughput. You may need to use wifi or bluetooth.

Comment: @GabeSechan Added code sample. Its possible, becouse TV remote does it. Need about 50 requests, in 3 secounds

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same IR protocol on your TV remote as on the phone?  Because there isn't just one IR protocol.  Also, I've never seen a TV remote make anything even close to that-  last time I tried to program my remote it was more like 1 request/second.

Comment: But really the only thing you can do is pick a higher frequency from the range of frequencies the IRManager supports and your receiver supports.  See getCarrierFrequencies ()

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for tips. Its really wierd remote, thats why I used it. Its used in room light system, to change brightness of the lights.